# How to define custom wicket tag

Tags: wicket

I could not find a wicket tag like wicket:include? Can anyone suggest me anything? I want to include/inject raw source into html files? If there is no such utility, any suggestions to develop it?

**update**
i am looking for sth like jsp:include. this inclusion is expected to be handled on the server side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To do this, you'll need to implement your own [IComponentResolver](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/markup/resolver/IComponentResolver.html).

This [blog article](http://sanityresort.blogspot.com/2011/08/creating-custom-wicket-tag-resolver.html) shows an example somewhat resembling what you're after.

Comment: Thanks a lot! it definitely looks like something i am looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Is it raw markup that you want to include, or Wicket content?

If it's raw markup, even a simple `Label` can do that for you. If you call `setEscapeModelStrings( false)`, the string value of the model will be copied straight in the markup. (Watch out for potential XSS attacks though.)

"Including" Wicket markup is done via `Panel`s (or occasionally `Fragment`s)

Update: If you add more detail about the actual problem you need to solve, there's a good chance that we can find a more "wickety" solution, after all, JSP and Wicket are two different worlds and the mindset of one doesn't work very well in the other.

Comment: it could be both raw markup or wicket content. Though i agree, this may not be the wicket way to think. i want an inclusion pattern without explicit help of java code. please take a loot at what Don suggested.

Comment: But Wicket is all about the Java code mirroring HTML code. It's not a good practice to stray from this and practically everything can be achieved without it.

Comment: +1:  Though I did know of and posted something close to the request, this is good advice, and what I do usually is to just use a Label as you describe.